# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase' after updating nodejs version to 10.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have reactjs application in which firebase auth module is integrated. It works fine in nodejs 7, 8 and 9 version but when I'm try to run with nodejs 10.0 version it gives an error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase' ". This is my environment:-

```
OS: LINUX 16.04 LTS
NODE: 10.0
NPM: 5.6.0
Firebase: 4.13.1
```

Comment: remove node_modules folder and try to run `npm i` to reinstall :)

Comment: I did that but still don't working.

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: I have same problem too